# Scrolling individual cells inside a StringGrid

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe5

I have a string grid with fixed cell widths, but often the data which is being placed inside the cells is longer than what the cell can hold.

Is there a way that I can scroll within an individual cell?

Alternatively, if you can think of a different way of viewing the entirety of the cell in a slightly more elegant way, then that would be great as well!

Comment: The text which exceeds a cell rectangle is usually displayed as shortened with ellipsis and the whole content shown as a hint when the cell is hovered. That's the most common practice I've seen so far.

Comment: @TLama Thankyou, would you be able to show me how I can do that? I'm an student studying computing so my knowledge on delphi is fairly limited.